# Block folder access but allow subfolders

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying along with nginx and a php script block access to folders for non-members.

```
location ^~ /members/ {
    if ($cookie_amember_nr !~* [a-zA-Z0-9]+) { #not authorized
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://example.com/protect/new-rewrite?f=2&url=$request_uri?$args redirect;
    }
    set $file $document_root/data/new-rewrite/$cookie_amember_nr-2;
    if (!-f $file) { #have not access
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://example.com/no-access/folder/id/2?url=$request_uri?$args redirect;
    }    
    #everything is ok
}
```

This works fine but blocks access to the members folder and all subfolders

How do I make rules only for the members folder but that does not affect the sub folders
 
For example I want anyone to have access to the files inside /members/css/ /members/js/

Comment: Have you looked at the `auth_request` directive?https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html